# PermGen space with jetty

Tags: java, maven, jetty, maven-3

I'm developing a java web application where I'm using mavenlike tool of project managment. Now my trouble is that if i setted jetty for autoscan each 20 second in this way:

```
<!-- To launch embded jetty server -->
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-jetty-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <webAppConfig>
                    <contextPath>/${project.name}</contextPath>
                    <extraClasspath>target/classes;../services/target/classes;</extraClasspath>
                </webAppConfig>
                <scanTargets>
                    <scanTarget>target/classes</scanTarget>
                    <scanTarget>../services/target/classes</scanTarget>
                </scanTargets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Jetty starts in a correct way in fact i get:

> [INFO] Started Jetty Server
>
> [INFO] Starting scanner at interval of 20 seconds.

But at the first scan i get the following error:

> ERROR ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
>
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

How can I do to fix it?

**Update 1**

I try to increse a PermGen space from my Eclipse Ide in this way:

[image]

but after the first scan i get back the same error.

How can I do to fix it?

Comment: It means your webapp's classloader is not getting unloaded when your webapp gets redeployed. Perhaps you have defined ThreadLocals?

Comment: I don't know the mean to ThreadLocals , can you explain what could be the problem and link resolve it

Comment: If you don't know what ThreadLocals are, you probably aren't using them. :) But the classloader is definitely not getting unloaded.

Answer (score 6):

Put this under the `<configuration>` element: `<jvmArgs>-XX:PermSize=256M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M</jvmArgs>`

So the Maven plugin will look like this:

```
<!-- To launch embded jetty server -->
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-jetty-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <jvmArgs>-XX:PermSize=256M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M</jvmArgs>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <webAppConfig>
                    <contextPath>/${project.name}</contextPath>
                    <extraClasspath>target/classes;../services/target/classes;</extraClasspath>
                </webAppConfig>
                <scanTargets>
                    <scanTarget>target/classes</scanTarget>
                    <scanTarget>../services/target/classes</scanTarget>
                </scanTargets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

NOTE: if it fails with a message that it can't allocate so much memory use lower numbers.

Comment: thanks for you suggest but doesn't work yet. I'm becoming crazy :(

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried running under JDK8?  PermGen has been replaced with MetaSpace and might fix your PermGen issues: http://www.infoq.com/news/2013/03/java-8-permgen-metaspace

Jetty also has some documentation about preventing classloader leaks that might fill up permgen: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/preventing-memory-leaks.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to increase MaxPermGen space with -XX:MaxPermSize=512m passed to MAVEN_OPTS.